# How to left align the list of skills on resume?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, resume

**This is what I currently have:**
[image]

Latex code:

```
\section{Skills}
 \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0.15in, label={}]
    \small{\item{
     \textbf{Languages}{: proficient in Python, HTML, CSS; familiar with C++, SQL} \\
     \textbf{Frameworks}{: Django, Pytest, Bootstrap} \\
     \textbf{Tools}{: Git, Sass, SAS Analytics, IBM SPSS, Microsoft Access, Excel} \\
     \textbf{Libraries}{: Requests, Beautiful Soup, Selenium, Matplotlib, Pillow, Docx}
    }}
 \end{itemize}
```

**Desired output:**

[image]

As you can see, the skill category is right-aligned while the list of skills is left aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up how `\item` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{Skills}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=.95in]
        \small
        \item[\textbf{Languages}:] proficient in Python, HTML, CSS; familiar with C++, SQL
        \item[\textbf{Frameworks}:] Django, Pytest, Bootstrap
        \item[\textbf{Tools}:] Git, Sass, SAS Analytics, IBM SPSS, Microsoft Access, Excel
        \item[\textbf{Libraries}:] Requests, Beautiful Soup, Selenium, Matplotlib, Pillow, Docx
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]